# selection.exit().remove() method does not do overwriting or deletion

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a problem with updating existing layout data.

I have nodes, where every node consists of group with circle and foreignObject nested. After nodes data update, content of each node (circle and foreignObject) is added one more time to group element.

I am pretty sure that problem is somewhere between `enter().data()` and `exit().remove()` methods.

My code:

```
var node = mainSvg.select('.nodes').selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id
    });

node.enter().append('g');

var circle = node.append('circle');
var foreignObject = node.append('foreignObject');

node.exit().remove();
```

I dropped out needles code, so it could be as cleaner as it can.

Comment: Sounds like your matching doesn't work, i.e. there are duplicate IDs.

Comment: There are no duplicate id's. It is 100% percent right.

Comment: Ok, could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff No, I couldn't. Quite much was done, I cannot reproduce it

Comment: So the problem is solved?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff no, unfortunately no. Still cannot solve it. I would post the right answer.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff The problem is gone if I remove all nodes content before adding new one, but it is rude method to solve the problem. My opinion is that enter() method looks after the node's group element, not for foreignObject and circle.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what exactly is there behind exit and enter methods, but I solved the problem.

**Old code**

```
var node = mainSvg.select('.nodes').selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id
    });

node.enter().append('g');

var circle = node.append('circle');
var foreignObject = node.append('foreignObject');

node.exit().remove();
```

**New code**

```
var node = mainSvg.select('.nodes').selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id
    }).enter().append('g');

var circle = node.append('circle');
var foreignObject = node.append('foreignObject');

mainSvg.select('.nodes').selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id
    }).exit().remove();
```

And it works fine. Thanks to @LarsKothoff for patience and will to help.